# Filter on a mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to filter data on a select because there is too much options.
I did it like this :

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Unit.." (change)="onTabChange(element, $event.value.id, 'assignedUnit')">
            <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="filterListCareUnit($event.target.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let careUnit of listCareUnits" [value]="careUnit">
              {{ careUnit.label }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

on key up, i'm calling `filterListCareUnit($event.target.value)`

but in this function i don't know to use the filter rxjs

I have my `listCareUnits` and I want to remove all object which don't contains the `$event.target.value`

for now I did this but clearly don't work, my list always contains the same items :

```
  filterListCareUnit(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.listCareUnits.filter((unit) => unit.label.indexOf(val));
  }
```

Newbie at angular/rxjs ..
Thanks for the help

Comment: You are not using rxjs in that code. It is being used by material2 internally. Anyway, your problem is most likely you are not assigning the filtered list back to your listCareUnits var: `this.listCareUnits = this.listCareUnits.filter((unit) => unit.label.indexOf(val) > -1);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to assign the returned filtered list.

```
 filterListCareUnit(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.listCareUnits = this.listCareUnits.filter((unit) => unit.label.indexOf(val) > -1);
  }
```

But in order not to lose the data of your initial array, it will be better to use another array for processing that will always contain your initial set of data.

```
anotherArray = this.listCareUnits;
filterListCareUnit(val) {
        console.log(val);
        this.listCareUnits = this.anotherArray.filter((unit) => unit.label.indexOf(val) > -1);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that this has been answered, but you could also have used "mat-select-filter".

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-filter

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: atm, all these mat-select filtering libs have are not yet polished enough to be used in production. make sure you check double check and triple check its usage before introducing it to your project.

Answer (score 2):

here a quick workaround without code in ts file

```html
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="result">
    <input matInput placeholder="filter.." #filterplc>
    <div  *ngFor="let opt of options ">
    <mat-option *ngIf="opt.includes(filterplc.value)"
                [value]="opt">
      {{opt}}
    </mat-option>
      </div>
  </mat-select>
```